# How to avoid the page refresh of user control?

Tags: jquery, updatepanel, scriptmanager, radajaxmanager, radajaxloadingpanel

I have one parent page (aspx) which has one user control (ascx) this ascx has onemore user control there i am using a checkbox and dropdownlist .On checkbox check the postback event is triggered that is server side method is executed (same for the dropdown list). The problem is when i check the value of checkbox the whole page gets reloaded. I want to avoid the entire page reload(refresh). I tried using the update panel and ajaxmanagerproxy.

Comment: _I tried using the update panel and ajaxmanagerproxy_ no code provided of your tries.

Comment: <asp:UpdatePanel ID="upPanel" runat="server" UpdateMode="Always">
    <ContentTemplate>